# Return identity value from an insert in a generalized way in C#

Tags: c#, java, sql, oracle, sqlite

I'd like to be able to get the identity value back after calling an insert statement. I can do this now and it works fine with SQL server by adding SET @RETURN_VALUE = SCOPE_IDENTITY() and using an out parameter.

The problem is that this would only work with SQL server and I need to support Oracle and SQLite as well. Now I know could write separate code for each but is there a generic way to do this in .NET?

Java for example has a getGeneratedKeys method which can be called after the insert, returning a result set of generated column names and values.

Any similar construct in .NET?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately each DBMS has its own specific way of retrieving the last inserted identity value, so you have to write specific code for each DBMS.

Comment: They aren't even called identities in other dbs besides SQL Server.

Comment: True. Oracle calls it a sequence. But that's why Java has that method. So that JDBC providers can implement their own way of doing it as part of the standard API. I figured .NET might have the same.

Comment: OK I guess I can live with it.  I'll write a Helper class with different implementations.